# Can I make a "view" in active directory to list all people

Tags: active-directory

Totally new to AD. I would like to create a "view" that lists all people by alphabetical order, and hopefully would include their employee ID field.

Comment: Have you tried writing queries in ADUC? That's where I'd start. You can write a query that satisfies your requirements and then save it for future use.

Comment: See [this](https://i.imgur.com/pBbO2rc.png) section in ADUC.

Comment: Right. Create a query for user accounts where name has a value. That will list all user accounts in the domain. You can sort the results any way you like and can add any of the available columns to the list. The actual query string will be: (&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(name=*))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a query in ADUC for user accounts where name has a value. That will list all user accounts in the domain. You can sort the results any way you like and can add any of the available columns to the list. The actual query string will be:

**(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(name=*))**

Comment: This is working. But I want to exclude groups....

Comment: You should create the query only for users, not groups. Rather than "building the query with the available selections, create a custom query and paste this into the LDAP string section: (&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(name=*))

Comment: I had made a mistake now I have fixed it. Found how to add remove columns. Any way to edit a column right in the query? Also I am trying to filter out system accounts, but I can probably figure it out.

Comment: The query is working perfectly, I am just looking for the syntax to exclude system accounts, i.e. ones that will not have an employee Number.

Comment: @BryanSchmiedeler Your question says 'Employee ID' but your comment says 'employee Number', both are valid attributes for user objects. Add `(!employeeNumber=*)` or `(!employeeID=*)` to the LDAP filter accordingly.

Comment: That won't help me as all employee's are blank, and the reason I am creating this query is to give someone a quick way to see all these people and to enter their employee number.

Comment: @BryanSchmiedeler It wouldn't hurt to include those details in your question as requirements.

Comment: Point taken.....